# Trying to set model function database connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model

I'm trying to connect to my remove server in the model public function like this:

```
public function mods()
{   
    return $this->belongsTo('SCM\Files', 'featured_mod_id', 'fid')->on('sky')->with('author');
}
```

I'm trying to set `SCM\Files` model to connect to the database called "sky" but I get

> Call to undefined relationship [mods] on model [SCM\FeaturedContent]

in return

Comment: u would like to use a different database for the model or only one function?? is Files ur model name?? try to write Files::class instead of  'SCM\Files'

Comment: @Borna I have wrote "Files::class" it's the same, but I am trying to make it use the "sky" database connection instead of the default db connection

Comment: Why don't you simply add this `protected $connection = 'connection-name';` to your `SCM\Files`?

Comment: exactly use protected $connection = 'connection-name'; if u would like to use  different database for specific model's all function https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: and are u sure that belongsTo is right??? what is the tables structure???